# Integral of signum and a root

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, radicals, upper-lower-bounds

I need to evaluate (or at least find an upper bound) of this type of integrals:
$$ \int_0 ^{\frac{1}{2}} \text{sign}\left(\frac{1}{2} - x\right) \frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{2}-x\right)^s} \text{d}x \,,$$
for $s \in (0,1)$ and where *sign* is the signum function. I know from *Mathematica* that the integral converges for a fixed value of $s$ but I need the general answer in terms of $s$. Thanks for any ideas on how to proceed!

Comment: MMA gives the following answer: $$\begin{cases}
 -\frac{2^{s-1}}{s-1} & \Re(s)<1 \\
 \text{Integrate}\left[\left(\frac{1}{2}-x\right)^{-s}
   \text{sgn}\left(\frac{1}{2}-x\right),\left\{x,0,\fra
   c{1}{2}\right\},\text{Assumptions}\to \Re(s)\geq
   1\right] & \text{True}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Not sure what MMA stands for but thanks @Dr.SonnhardGraubner so much! Haven't realised that it is that simple... O:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**. By the change of variable 
$$
u=\frac12-x,\quad du=-dx,
$$ observing that $\text{sign}\left(\frac{1}{2} - x\right)=1 $ for $0<x<\frac12$, one just gets
$$
 \int_0 ^{\frac{1}{2}} \text{sign}\left(\frac{1}{2} - x\right) \frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{2}-x\right)^s} \text{d}x = \int_0 ^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{du}{u^s},\quad s \in (0,1) . 
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, I haven't realised that it is that simple... O:-)